# Use auto scroll stack cards js or gsap

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have a standard example of stacking cards, but I need to use auto-scroll. Everything works fine until I go `onEnterBack`.

This works well if I don't use position: sticky;

View on [codepen](https://codepen.io/vildxtom-the-sasster/pen/XWOYEqz)

HTML:

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card">7</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
}
.card {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 0 5rem 10rem;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 2rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
  position: sticky;
  top: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  transform-origin: center top;
  height: 10vh;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

ScrollTrigger.config({ limitCallbacks: true });

const sections = gsap.utils.toArray(".card");

const scrolling = {
  enabled: true,
  events: "scroll,wheel,touchmove,pointermove".split(","),
  prevent: (e) => e.preventDefault(),
  disable() {
    if (scrolling.enabled) {
      scrolling.enabled = false;
      window.addEventListener("scroll", gsap.ticker.tick, { passive: true });
      scrolling.events.forEach((e, i) =>
        (i ? document : window).addEventListener(e, scrolling.prevent, {
          passive: false
        })
      );
    }
  },
  enable() {
    if (!scrolling.enabled) {
      scrolling.enabled = true;
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", gsap.ticker.tick);
      scrolling.events.forEach((e, i) =>
        (i ? document : window).removeEventListener(e, scrolling.prevent)
      );
    }
  }
};

function goToSection(section, anim, i) {
  console.log(scrolling.enabled);

  if (scrolling.enabled) {
    // skip if a scroll tween is in progress
    scrolling.disable();

    gsap.to(window, {
      scrollTo: { y: section, autoKill: false },
      onComplete: scrolling.enable,
      duration: 1
    });

    anim && anim.restart();
  }

  console.log(section);
}

sections.forEach((section, i) => {
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: section,
    start: "top bottom-=1",
    end: "bottom top+=1",
    markers: true,
    onEnter: () => goToSection(section),
    onEnterBack: () => goToSection(section)
  });
});
```